# How to write data to mutiple QFiles

Tags: qt, qtextstream

I am trying to add a line to the file every time i receive data, and if the number of lines exceed 10 lines, create new files to store the data until create 5 files, but i encoutered a problem, that is the application will crash at the 56th line : `QTextStream stream(current_record_file);` , the  code are :

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    simulateReceiveData();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::simulateReceiveData()
{
    while(file_count < 5){
        qDebug()<<"on recording ...";
        if(file_count == 1 && msg_line_count == -1){
            //create the very first new file
            record_file_name_prefix = "D:/Project/MessageRecording";
            QString record_file_name = record_file_name_prefix + "(1).asc";
            qDebug()<<"record_file_name is"<<record_file_name;
            QFile file(record_file_name);
            if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)){
                qDebug()<<QString("Fail to open file : %1").arg(record_file_name);
                return;
            }

            //write the header
            current_record_file = &file;
            QTextStream stream(current_record_file);
            stream << "START\r\n";
            msg_line_count = 0;

        }else if(msg_line_count == 10){
            //write footer to privious file
            QTextStream stream(current_record_file);
            stream << "END";
            stream.flush();
            current_record_file->close();

            //create next new file
            file_count++;
            QString record_file_name = record_file_name_prefix + QString("(%1).%2").arg(file_count).arg("asc");
            QFile file(record_file_name);
            if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate))
                return;
            current_record_file = &file;  //redirect to the new created file
            msg_line_count = 0;
        }else{
            //write the main body
            QTextStream stream(current_record_file); // CRASH HERE !
            stream <<"0.0000 0 Rx 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00\r\n";
            msg_line_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

**mainwindow.h :**

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    void simulateReceiveData();
    int file_count = 1;//number of files
    int msg_line_count = -1;//number of lines in one file
    QString record_file_name_prefix;
    QFile* current_record_file = nullptr;//point to currently written file
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what the state of the application is, and use that information to determine what went wrong. Most likely you have some undefined behavior somewhere (like dangling pointer/reference dereference).

Comment: Basic c++ - your QFile instance goes out-of-scope and therefore you have a dangling ointer

Comment: I looked up Dangling pointer in Wikipedia, it is really such issue, so i need to make all the 5 QFile instance alive, i will study how to make it tomorrow ~

Answer (score 0):

As stated by chehrlic's comment, you are accessing a (dangling) pointer to an object that has gone out-of-scope.

Two solutions exist:

1. Reopen the file on each write (may be incompatible with `QFile::Truncate` and less efficient)
2. Use `QFile current_record_file` as a member, instead of `QFile* current_record_file`. This seems to me the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's reply, i tried m7913d's second solution, and it can create multiple QFiles now ! The magic point is after you close last QFile current_record_file, and reset its file name by `current_record_file.setFileName(record_file_name);`, programm will help us create new file automatically. The new worrkable code are :

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QThread>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    simulateReceiveData();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::simulateReceiveData()
{
    while(file_count < 5){
        qDebug()<<"on recording ...";

        if(file_count == 1 && msg_line_count == -1){
            //create the very first new file
            record_file_name_prefix = "D:/Project/MessageRecording";
            QString record_file_name = record_file_name_prefix + QString::number(file_count) + ".asc";
            current_record_file.setFileName(record_file_name);
            if (!current_record_file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)){
                qDebug()<<QString("Fail to open file : %1").arg(record_file_name);
                return;
            }

            //write the header
            QTextStream stream(&current_record_file);
            stream << "START\r\n";
            msg_line_count = 0;

        }else if(msg_line_count == 10){
            //write footer to privious file
            QTextStream stream(&current_record_file);
            stream << "END";
            stream.flush();
            current_record_file.close();

            file_count++;
            QString record_file_name = record_file_name_prefix + QString::number(file_count) +  ".asc";
            qDebug()<<"new record file is"<<record_file_name;
            current_record_file.setFileName(record_file_name);
            if (!current_record_file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)){
                qDebug()<<QString("Fail to open file : %1").arg(record_file_name);
                return;
            }

            QTextStream stream2(&current_record_file);
            stream2 << "START\r\n";
            msg_line_count = 0;

        }else{
            //write the main body
            QTextStream stream(&current_record_file); // CRASH HERE !
            stream <<file_count<<" 0.0000 0 Rx 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00\r\n";
            msg_line_count++;
            QThread::sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    void simulateReceiveData();
    int file_count = 1;//number of files
    int msg_line_count = -1;//number of lines in one file
    QString record_file_name_prefix;
    QFile current_record_file;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```